# How I keep UISlider state when changing ViewControllers? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I would like to keep the State of an UISlider after to change between View Controllers, and make to work the UISlider in another View Controllers (now it is only working in the current View Controller of the UISlider)

I'm a beginner to Swift and generally Xcode. Thank you in advance for your time and help :)

First, I have a View Controller with a class for the Music:

```
class MusicHelper {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()

    var musicBackgroundIntro:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        do {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")
            try musicBackgroundIntro = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
            musicBackgroundIntro.numberOfLoops = -1
            musicBackgroundIntro.prepareToPlay()
            musicBackgroundIntro.play()

        } catch {
            print("Cannot play the file")
        }
    }

    func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        musicBackgroundIntro.stop()
    }
```

Second, I have another View Controller with the UISlider:

```
@IBOutlet weak var SliderMusic: UISlider!

@IBAction func checkStateSliderMusic(_ sender: UISlider) {
    MusicHelper.sharedHelper.musicBackgroundIntro.volume = sender.value
}
```

Any idea that how will be possible to apply the UISlider in another View Controllers and keep the state (modification of volume)?

Answer (score 0):

When your view controller loads you can set the sliders value based on the current volume value. In the `viewDidLoad` method of `UIViewController` set the value of your slider.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    musicSlider.value = Float(MusicHelper.sharedHelper.musicBackgroundIntro.volume)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that it is working well in the same View Controller of the UISlider, Any idea that how will be possible to apply the UISlider in another View Controllers and keep the state (modification of volume) when back and forward between View Controllers?